# Hero Slider: First slide does not load, initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm not too familiar with jQuery and/or JavaScript, but I am trying to use [Hero Slider](http://codyhouse.co/gem/hero-slider/) for a site I'm building. I have pretty much modified the code to do what I'd like, but the first slide doesn't seem to load for some reason. Oddly, it shows up just fine when the slider loops back to the beginning slide. If I were to venture a guess, I'd say that something isn't loading in the right order, but I can't figure out the error. JQuery is being called in the head while the script (code below) is being called just before the `</body>`. I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxpfvf1b/) and I would be very appreciative if anyone could provide insight about why this isn't working properly. Also, though this is much less important, I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me where the little dots in the upper corners are coming from.

HTML

```
<section class="cd-hero">
    <ul class="cd-hero-slider autoplay">
        <li>
            <div class="cd-full-width">
                <h2>1. Slide title here</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, explicabo.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="cd-full-width">
                <h2>2. Slide title here</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, explicabo.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var slidesWrapper = $('.cd-hero-slider');

    //check if a .cd-hero-slider exists in the DOM 
    if ( slidesWrapper.length > 0 ) {
        var primaryNav = $('.cd-primary-nav'),
            sliderNav = $('.cd-slider-nav'),
            navigationMarker = $('.cd-marker'),
            slidesNumber = slidesWrapper.children('li').length,
            visibleSlidePosition = 0,
            autoPlayId,
            autoPlayDelay = 5000;

        //upload videos (if not on mobile devices)
        uploadVideo(slidesWrapper);

        //autoplay slider
        setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);

        //on mobile - open/close primary navigation clicking/tapping the menu icon
        primaryNav.on('click', function(event){
            if($(event.target).is('.cd-primary-nav')) $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
        });

        //change visible slide
        sliderNav.on('click', 'li', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var selectedItem = $(this);
            if(!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {
                // if it's not already selected
                var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index(),
                    activePosition = slidesWrapper.find('li.selected').index();

                if( activePosition < selectedPosition) {
                    nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
                } else {
                    prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
                }

                //this is used for the autoplay
                visibleSlidePosition = selectedPosition;

                updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, selectedPosition);
                updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, selectedPosition+1);
                //reset autoplay
                setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);
            }
        });
    }

    function nextSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n){
        visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
            visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
        });

        container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
        checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
    }

    function prevSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n){
        visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
            visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
        });

        container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
        checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
    }

    function updateSliderNavigation(pagination, n) {
        var navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');
        navigationDot.removeClass('selected');
        pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');
    }

    function setAutoplay(wrapper, length, delay) {
        if(wrapper.hasClass('autoplay')) {
            clearInterval(autoPlayId);
            autoPlayId = window.setInterval(function(){autoplaySlider(length)}, delay);
        }
    }

    function autoplaySlider(length) {
        if( visibleSlidePosition < length - 1) {
            nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
            visibleSlidePosition +=1;
        } else {
            prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, 0);
            visibleSlidePosition = 0;
        }
        updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, visibleSlidePosition+1);
        updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition);
    }

    function uploadVideo(container) {
        container.find('.cd-bg-video-wrapper').each(function(){
            var videoWrapper = $(this);
            if( videoWrapper.is(':visible') ) {
                // if visible - we are not on a mobile device 
                var videoUrl = videoWrapper.data('video'),
                    video = $('<video loop><source src="'+videoUrl+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+videoUrl+'.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>');
                video.appendTo(videoWrapper);
                // play video if first slide
                if(videoWrapper.parent('.cd-bg-video.selected').length > 0) video.get(0).play();
            }
        });
    }

    function checkVideo(hiddenSlide, container, n) {
        //check if a video outside the viewport is playing - if yes, pause it
        var hiddenVideo = hiddenSlide.find('video');
        if( hiddenVideo.length > 0 ) hiddenVideo.get(0).pause();

        //check if the select slide contains a video element - if yes, play the video
        var visibleVideo = container.children('li').eq(n).find('video');
        if( visibleVideo.length > 0 ) visibleVideo.get(0).play();
    }

    function updateNavigationMarker(marker, n) {
        marker.removeClassPrefix('item').addClass('item-'+n);
    }

    $.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
        //remove all classes starting with 'prefix'
        this.each(function(i, el) {
            var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
                return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
            });
            el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
        });
        return this;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, the first `<li>` does not have any class. If you add  `<li class="selected from-right">` to the first `<li>`, the first slide appears.

Also, to remove the dots before the slides just add `ul{list-style-type:none;}` in the css.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! This is exactly what I needed.